# Create supply chain project in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Helo,

I need to create a new project where there is a long and complex transaction chain
(User registers, uploads documents, sends physical goods, money transfers, etc).

There are many possible branchings in these steps and each includes multiple steps (item sent, in transit, on destination, etc, etc).

Is there a framework (Ruby or otherwise) I can use to easily create & maintain such a complex chain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect task for a State Machine. It can handle the states of an entity (ordered, paid, shipped, etc.) and you can define what should happen during state transitions.